# IN Query Expression . (Error 3075). MS ACESSS

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]**SQL Code:** `SELECT Alan1, Alan2, Alan3, Alan4, A.A_Ihbar_Sayısı, B.B_Ihbar_Sayısı, C.C_Ihbar_Sayısı FROM A INNER JOIN B  ON A.Alan4 = B.Alan4 AND A.Alan3 = B.Alan3 AND A.Alan2 = B.Alan2 INNER JOIN C ON B.Alan4 = C.Alan4 AND B.Alan3 = C.Alan3 AND B.Alan2 = C.Alan2;`

I get error in query expression . (Error 3075).I'm sure I didn't make a syntax error. How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access has arcane syntax requirements, such as parentheses in the `FROM` clause for multiple `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT Alan1, Alan2, Alan3, Alan4, A.A_Ihbar_Sayısı, B.B_Ihbar_Sayısı, C.C_Ihbar_Sayısı FROM (A INNER JOIN
      B
      ON A.Alan4 = B.Alan4 AND A.Alan3 = B.Alan3 AND A.Alan2 = B.Alan2
     ) INNER JOIN
     C
     ON B.Alan4 = C.Alan4 AND B.Alan3 = C.Alan3 AND B.Alan2 = C.Alan2;
```